# How to make a class accessible globally in a Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a global helper to store site settings in my Laravel application. Meaning, I need a helper to set settings from a controller and access that settings object from anywhere using the same helper. I don't need to store these settings on a database or in files. That's why I need these kinds of functionality.

What is did are as follows,

- Create a class in `app/Helpers` directory called `SettingsHelper` and auto load the directory.

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class SettingsHelper{

    protected $vars;

    public function all(){
        return $this->vars;
    }

    public function get($key, $default = null){

        if (is_array($this->vars) && array_key_exists($key, $this->vars)) {
            return $this->vars[$key];
        }

        return $default;
    }

    public function put($key, $value){
        return $this->vars[$key] =$value;
    }

}
```

- Create a helper function to resolve the class if not already resolved

```
if ( ! function_exists('settings')) {

    function settings(){

        if (app('\App\Helpers\SettingsHelper')) {
            return app('\App\Helpers\SettingsHelper');
        }

        return app()->make('\App\Helpers\SettingsHelper');
    }

}
```

- Set and get setting using the helper

```
settings()->put('test', 'test2');
dd(settings()->all());
```

But `null` is returned. I tried dumping `settings()->put('test', 'test2')` and it returned the passed value `test2`.

Is this the correct approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [register your class as a singleton in the application container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#binding-basics) before you can use it. Otherwise, the `app()` function will create a new instance on every use. You can also give the instance a name in the container, this way, you don't have to create your own global function.

In your `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
$this->app->singleton('settings', function ($app) {
    return new \App\Helpers\SettingsHelper;
});
```

And now you can use your class with:

```
app('settings')->put('test', 'test2');
dd(app('settings')->all());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a service provider `php artisan make:provider HelperServiceProvider`

Then in the register method do something like:

```
public function register()
{
    foreach (glob(app_path().'/Helpers/*.php') as $filename) {
        require_once($filename);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a singleton in a provider, example `AppServiceProvider.php`.

```
use App\Helpers\SettingsHelper;

$this->app->singleton(SettingsHelper::class, function ($app) {
    return new SettingsHelper($vars); // create your class with the vars you need
});
```

Everywhere in your app there can only be 1 settings helper and you can get it like so.

```
use App\Helpers\SettingsHelper;

app(SettingsHelper::class);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This method is working but i cannot update the `$vars` variable in the `SettingsHelper` class. It returns the default value always.

Comment: Whats your approach?